# GatsbyJS Service Worker configuration doesn't respect "networkFirst", keeps serving stale data

Tags: caching, service-worker, browser-cache, gatsby, workbox

I have a GatsbyJS website that I'm deploying to Netlify. Whenever I navigate to my website, the Service Worker serves me a stale version of the website and sends a request in the background so that I get a fresher version next time. **I don't think it's acceptable that a user who goes to my site sees a version that may be several days old.** I want the Service Worker to fetch a fresh version as long as network is available, and serve the stale version only in offline mode. I'm unable to find any documentation on how to make that happen.

Based on [this GatsbyJS doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/) and [this Workbox doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build) I figured that it should work to change the strategy from `staleWhileRevalidate` to `networkFirst`. They don't provide a complete example anywhere, so I had to guess the syntax, and it looks like my guess was not correct. **Can anyone provide a complete example of how to configure gatsby-plugin-offline to achieve reasonable behavior?**

Comment: I have no experience with gatsby's offline, but have you tried removing the worker first, then add it again? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/#remove

Comment: I have, although without that plugin (I don't have real users yet so I don't have to worry about removing an old service worker from my users' browsers).

Answer (score 13):

This is a quite a long answer so I've split it into 3 parts.

### The problem

Gatsby's offline plugin uses Google's workbox under the hood to do both pre-caching and runtime caching. Workbox has different [runtime caching strategies](https://web.dev/runtime-caching-with-workbox/) provided by the [workbox-strategies package](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies). These include [stale-while-revalidate](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#stale-while-revalidate), [cache first (cache falling back to network)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#cache_first_cache_falling_back_to_network) and [network first (network falling back to cache)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_first_network_falling_back_to_cache).

gatsby-plugin-offline sets up appropriate [caching strategies for different URLs](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/f8b7317c435fa9573c1265ba7911f9a785615553/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/src/gatsby-node.js#L134-L156). For example:

- CSS, JS and files in the static directory use `CacheFirst` as they have hashed, unique URLS and can be safely served from cache.
- *page-data.json* files use `StaleWhileRevalidate` because they don't have hashed URLS.

> Note: the [Gatsby docs for gatsby-plugin-offline](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blame/f8b7317c435fa9573c1265ba7911f9a785615553/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/README.md#L151) (as of May 2020) says that *page-data.json* files use `NetworkFirst` but [they actually use `StaleWhileRevalidate`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/f8b7317c435fa9573c1265ba7911f9a785615553/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/src/gatsby-node.js#L144).

Files that don't have specific handlers set up in gatsby-plugin-offline (e.g. HTML files for first load) [use a cache first policy](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1540#issuecomment-399121797). The plugin uses [generateSW from workbox-build](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-build#.generateSW) under the hood. Note: I couldn't actually find reference to this in the docs, just the comment I linked to but I did experiment and HTML pages are definitely cached by the service worker, despite not being in the the `runtimeCaching` list.

So I think your problem of users seeing stale pages is because the HTML on first load and the *page-data.json* files are both served from the cache by the service worker.

### Should you fix it

There's a trade off between using `NetworkFirst` and `CacheFirst` (or `StaleWhileRevalidate`). `NetworkFirst` is optimised for accurate data and the slight expense of speed. Whereas `CacheFirst` and `StaleWhileRevalidate` serve straight from cache so are optimised for performance at the expense of having the most up-to-date data. Both have the benefit of resilience in case of a network outage.

So it probably depends per use-case based on things like type of website, content and audience. For example:

- a blog with content that doesn't get updated often could probably safely use `StaleWhileRevalidate`, or even `CacheFirst` for individual posts.
- A website where you know the majority of your uses are using desktop computers over fast, wired, reliable internet connections, means using `NetworkFirst` is probably appropriate.
- A website showing something time-sensitive where you'd prefer to see the latest content would make sense to use `NetworkFirst`.

### How to fix it

I think there are 2 main ways to solve this: refresh the page when updates are available, or change the caching policy to be `NetworkFirst`.

#### Refreshing the page

Gatsby provides a [`onServiceWorkerUpdateReady`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onServiceWorkerUpdateReady) hook for this purpose. So you could leave the default cache first behaviour as-is but use this hook to refresh the page.

The simplest way is to reload the page when there's an update in the service worker:

```js
// gatsby-browser.js
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => window.location.reload(true);
```

However, this can be intrusive and un-prompted so isn't necessarily a great user experience. The alternative is to prompt the user to update. This is what the [Gatsby docs suggests](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-offline-support-with-a-service-worker/#displaying-a-message-when-a-service-worker-updates):

```js
// gatsby-browser.js
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => {
  const answer = window.confirm(
    `This application has been updated. ` +
      `Reload to display the latest version?`
  )

  if (answer === true) {
    window.location.reload()
  }
}
```

If you're not a fan of the native browser prompt (I'm not!) then a third option is to prompt the user via some custom UI. Something like:

```js
// gatsby-browser.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => {
    const root = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
            <p>
                Acme has been updated in the&nbsp;background.
                <br />
                Refresh to see the latest&nbsp;version.
            </p>
            <button onClick={() => window.location.reload(true)}>
                Refresh
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => document.body.removeChild(root)}>
                Close
            </button>
        </div>,
        root
    );
};
```

> Note: if you're going down this route and implementing as a dialog then please [make sure it's accessible](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html).

#### Use NetworkFirst

I think this is what you're after as it answers your "I want the Service Worker to fetch a fresh version as long as network is available".

Override [the workbox config](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline/#overriding-workbox-configuration) with gatsby-plugin-offline to change the runtime caching policies to use `NetworkFirst` appropriately. Use the `runtimeCaching` property to do something like:

```js
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
            options: {
                workboxConfig: {
                    runtimeCaching: [
                        {
                            urlPattern: /(\.js$|\.css$|static\/)/,
                            handler: `CacheFirst`,
                        },
                        {
                            urlPattern: /^https?:.*\/page-data\/.*\/(page-data|app-data)\.json$/,
                            handler: `NetworkFirst`,
                            options: {
                                networkTimeoutSeconds: 1,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            urlPattern: /^https?:.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg|gif|tiff|js|woff|woff2|json|css)$/,
                            handler: `StaleWhileRevalidate`,
                        },
                        {
                            urlPattern: /^https?:\/\/fonts\.googleapis\.com\/css/,
                            handler: `StaleWhileRevalidate`,
                        },
                        {
                            urlPattern: /\/$/,
                            handler: `NetworkFirst`,
                            options: {
                                networkTimeoutSeconds: 1,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        },
    ]
};
```

This is the default runtimeCaching that gatsby-plugin-offline uses with 2 key changes: the following rules are both using `NetworkFirst`:

- *page-data.json* files
- HTML routes (that end in a /) - I've assumed your HTML pages all end with a / and if they don't you can use something like [gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-force-trailing-slashes/).